# Firebase Real Time Database Has Been Deleted but Can still log in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Yesterday my firebase app was working fine, and all of a sudden the Real-time database has been deleted. Is anyone else experiencing this? I can log in ok, but all my clients cannot fetch their data and neither can I. Please tell me this has happened before and it will come back to normal. I am currently on a flame plan with firebase.

Not a good look with my clients =(

any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

C

Comment: Your user account is created using firebase auth. So you need to delete account by going into firebase auth section. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase Real Time Database** and **Firebase Auth** both are different section and keep data separately. If your Firebase Real Time database has been deleted that means not deleted data of Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Support was awesome in helping, however just received an email that they did not restore my data. Really weird, that it popped up out of nowhere. Has anyone else experienced this? In my console, the data branches where not there and it all looked deleted, I then had to click create a database and go to Real-time database and all of a sudden, an hour later, all my data showed on my screen. How is this possible? Crazy crazy crazy...